# How to render a 3D .dwg file that has a geolocation on Autodesk with a 3D map viewing?

Tags: reactjs, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, dwg, 3d-mapping

I have this .dwg file, and it has a lat and lng coordinates and I am trying to make it show on a 3D map rendered in Autodesk viewer, I am using reactJS, I would like guidance on how to get this end results please?

I tried running the .dwg file on autodesk and it's working but I am not sure how combine that with a map that shows it?, what kind of map should i Use and is there any resources available to help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way by using Mapbox and adding a 3D model to it,

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/

This was the best solution so far